# How to check for Inconsistent Respondents in System Usability Scale (SUS)?

Tags: sus, reliability

I'm trying to evaluate the validity of the SUS responses- I think it's also called *internal reliability* or *Response bias*.
How is this done for SUS?

Comment: I really think this is a question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/. It has little to do with user experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Cross Validated

Comment: It depends- if it's just a calculation, then yes it's more of a stats question. But if it requires to know which pairs of SUS questions ask for the same thing it's more UX.

Comment: @mmatti It's currently unclear exactly what you're asking, and the focus of your question will determine whether it's on topic or not.  In the mean time, I'm closing it, but if you improve the question, you can ask to have it reopened.

Comment: It is totally related to hci!!! Not offtopic to me. Maybe we need more context but it is interesting

Comment: I can see there are pairs of questions in SUS that try to measure the same thing, e.g. questions 2 and 3:
"2. I found CRR unnecessarily complex." 
"3. I thought CRR was easy to use." 
I'm sure these questions were designed to test for inconsistent answers. (User can't be agreeing with both these statements at the same time).

Answer (score 3):

When analyzing survey data you need to separate validity from reliability.

- Validity is a measurement of how *correct* the answer is.
- Reliability is a measure of how *consistent* the answer is.

Here's a graphical representation of the concept (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_%28psychometrics%29)):

[image]

In general, SUS has been found to be highly reliable and there is some strong support that it produces valid conclusions [1].

But you are probably more interested in determining if *your survey* results are valid for your problem. To answer this, my advice is to find some other measure of usability to correlate your results with (this is referred to as "convergent validity"). For instance, you could compare the results of a similar survey or expert evaluation of the interface with the SUS scores. Or you could compare task completion time (or some other quantitative measure of performance) of a user with previously gathered SUS scores, if they correlate then SUS has "predictive validity", which would be pretty convincing.

If you are interested in reliability, I suggest you use Chronbach's alpha. It is a combined measure of all correlations between questions and essentially means how likely is it that respondents answer questions in a similar way. Alternatively, you could rerun the test with the same participants and see if you get similar answers.

[1] Bangor,  A.,  Kortum,  P.  T.,  Miller,  J.  T.:  An  Empirical  Evaluation  of  the  System Usability Scale.  International Journal of Human-Computer Interaction.  24, 574--594 (2008)